# Sinch - shouldSendPushNotifications: called when recipient attempts to answer call from local notification

Tags: ios, sinch

I've implemented push-based calling which works fine, however this seems to have completely broken background calls.

When calling another user when they have the app in the background, but not closed, they receive the local notification as expected.

When launching the app from this notification, just after relaying the local notification the caller app immediately attempts to start a push call instead via shouldSendPushNotifications: - the crazy thing is this method is being called 10 times in rapid succession.

This will then go through on the recipient - now we have two calls to deal with, which ends up breaking my UI a bit. I've hacked around it to stop my app breaking, I now check if the client has already been initialised (it will be when handling local notifications, and it won't be when handling push), which seems to get around this issue.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? It only happens when both push and local are enabled in the Sinch client.

Comment: hello @lyptt can you please send me code or method of push which you have implement because when i implement this method it gives me error.

Answer (score 4):

The issue that `shouldSendPushNotifications:` is invoked multiple times, potentially with the same data provide (same push-data and push-payload) comes from that each such pair may represent one app installation for a particular user-id. So if you have uninstalled/installed the app many times on the same device, and with different options set on the `SINClient` (e.g. `setSupportPushNotifications` with NO and then YES), that may be part of that problem. Though we at Sinch are working on a solution for that, that would eliminate callbacks with identical information.

The fact that you may see `shouldSendPushNotifications:` being invoked even though the other client have begun answering the call is because the push mechanism is intended to be triggered based on a lack of response/acknowledgement by the other client within a certain time window. If the other client is in the in the background but with VoIP-mode enabled, it will send an ACK as soon as possible, which should prevent the push mechanism to trigger. But if that ACK is not received with the time window, the push-mechanism is triggered. So the push-mechanism, when used in conjunction with VoIP-mode can be considered a best-effort fallback-mechanism. Though in your case I suspect is related to the per-app-installation capabilities described in the previous section and we are working on improving this.

Still, because the push-mechanism may also be triggered in cases of say an untimely slow network-condition and that the ACK from another client takes longer than the "expected worst case" (which is currently 4 seconds), your app must handle the case of receiving a remote push notification even shortly after already receiving the didReceiveIncomingCall-callback. The key here is that it's not actually two different calls, but you can use the `SINNotificationResult` and `-[SINCallNotificationResult callId]` to identify that it's the same call. E.g. if you first receive a `didReceiveIncomingCall:`-callback and eventually use `-[SINClient relayLocalNotification:]`, then shortly after you receive the push notification and pass it to `-[SINClient relayRemotePushNotificationPayload:`], you will see that both "notification results" will contain the same `callId` and you can use that to manage your UI appropriately.

Thanks for your great feedback on the Sinch SDK and we at Sinch will be looking into ways to simplify the handling of push notifications and local notifications in general.

Comment: can you tell me how do we send the payload to the server.i am not able to send it can you give me brief idea how we can implement this thanx..